# Unity - Lots of 3d models

Tags: unity

I have about 60 3D models with each model being about 4mb in size.If i import them all to unity, my app will be about 240mb in size!.My app requires internet access so should i just upload my models to a server or something?

Comment: 240mb is still a lot less than many games on steam ;)

Comment: it is an android game

Comment: Is the app 240mb in size after going through Unity's asset pipeline? Or did you just estimate that size because your source assets are this big?

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes to the first

Comment: Personally I'm not a big fan of "forcing" users to download again after downloading a game/app (I think it's bad UX), but it certainly is a possibility. I'd first try using higher compression on textures and sounds to see if the quality is still good enough. Alternatively you could evaluate whether 240mb is really too big - there's quite a few games in the store that take >1gb.

Comment: 2 questions: what format are you using? How many polygons do the objects have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading your models at runtime doesn't solve the problem. Instead of doing a huge download when installing the game they now need to do a huge download when they start the game. Even worse is that they will have to download it from your servers instead of Google's content delivery network. This will be more expensive for you and likely less fast for your users.

You are also deceiving users about the real download size of your game, which people will take into account when giving their reviews of your game.

So instead of wondering how to get all that data onto the user's device, you should rather wonder if your game really *needs* to be 240 MB.

When you have 4 MB models in an android game, then those models might be overly detailed for the small screen size and limited hardware. A 4MB model would either have over 100.000 polygons or several MB of textures.

So you might want to look into reducing the number of vertices, into using lower resolution textures or into making more reuse of textures.

Comment: the models are small in size..it is the textures that are big..any suggestions?..Thanks

Comment: @MrCSS You mean any suggestions besides those I gave in the last sentence of the question?

Comment: Lol I didn't see that..Thank you again :)